# jQuery disabling submit-by-press on keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to disable the "Enter" button on the keyboard so that when the user press enter to submit the form, nothing happens, and doing something else rather than submitting the form, such as alerting "Using keyboard is not allowed."

Here is what I have done, `#calculator` is a button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#calculator").keydown(function(){
       console.log("Enter is disabled.");
return false;
     });
});
```

Currently on its submission the form results unexpectedly (for instance redirects to the target page but without any CSS loaded.

Comment: do you have some code?

Comment: return `false` on keypress event with keycode 13

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(e){
    if(e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)** event to check which key was pressed then check the code of the key using `e.keycode` or `e.which`, if it's `13` then prevent submitting form:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 
    if (code == 13 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: no unfortunately. However your function's logic is all OK as it is read

Answer (score 0):

For it, don't use submit button.

Use a div, style it like a button and submit the form using javascript on click of the div :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

For Disabling Keyboard

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
        alert('Using keyboard is not allowed')
}
```

For Disabling Enter

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(e){
    if(e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```